# How to split an array on duplicate elements in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

Assuming one can have arrays with consecutive duplicate elements, I'm looking for a way to turn this array:

```rb
['A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'F']
```

into this:

```rb
[['A', 'B', 'C'], ['C', 'D'], ['D','F']]
```

Please mind that for my particular case an array may not have more than 2 consecutive duplicate elements.

Comment: Your question isn’t clear. How would you split `%w[a b b b c]`? What have you tried, and why doesn’t that work for you?

Comment: Right. Yes. Please assume that you can't have more than 2 consecutive duplicate elements. Wording fixed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Enumerable#slice_when](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_when) does that.

```
arr = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'F']
p arr.slice_when{|a,b| a==b}.to_a

# =>[["A", "B", "C"], ["C", "D"], ["D", "F"]]
```

Comment: You should edit your answer and include the alternate form there. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
arr = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'F']

arr.chunk_while(&:!=).to_a
  #=> [["A", "B", "C"], ["C", "D"], ["D", "F"]]
```

See [Enumerable#chunk_while](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk_while).

Old-fashioned way:

```
arr.each_with_object([[]]) do |s,a|
  if s == a.last.last
    a << [s]
  else
    a.last << s
  end
end
  #=> [["A", "B", "C"], ["C", "D"], ["D", "F"]]
```